# remove gibberish prefix from a string

Tags: python

```
a = "aajfkdfvf_valid_name0" 
b = "gdhdhsdsdeeeeex_valid_name1"
```

How do I remove the gibberish from my string before valid so that I have something like this -

```
valid_name0
valid_name1
```

Comment: Will you always have the word valid or something like that in your input?

Comment: You can use `rfind()` method of string to get the index of `valid` in the strings

Comment: What if the gibberish contains the string "_valid"

Comment: Yes, I found ```rfind()``` to be the most efficient way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings always contains `valid` word, then you can try something like -

```
a = "aajfkdfvf_valid_name0" 
b = "gdhdhsdsdeeeeex_valid_name1"
for s in (a, b):
    print(s[s.rfind('valid'):])
```

So, even if the prefix contains `_` or substring `valid` in it, the output will be correct. Though if your valid substring contains the word `valid` multiple times, then this will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a split join approach for this.
Try this:

```
a = "aajfkdfvf_valid_name0" 
valid_a = '_'.join(a.split('_')[1:])
# 'valid_name0'
# can use maxsplit to split only once at the first _ and then take the remaining part of the string
another_valid_a = a.split('_',1)[1]
# valid_name0
```

Basically what this is doing is that it is splitting the original string at the _, then ignoring the first element and joining the remaining part again using _.

Comment: The second arg of `split` could be `1` for better efficiency. Use `a.split('_', 1)[1]`

Comment: agreed, maxsplit=1 and then `[1]` instead of `[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.sub` here:

```py
a = "aajfkdfvf_valid_name0" 
b = "gdhdhsdsdeeeeex_valid_name1"
inp = [a, b]
output = [re.sub(r'^[^_]+_', '', i) for i in inp]
print(output)  # ['valid_name0', 'valid_name1']
```

Answer (score 0):

The other approaches seem a bit too *over-engineered* for this task, at least in my opinion.

If you already know that the gibberish comes before the first underscore `_`  character, you can just do a single `str.split` and discard the first split result:

```py
a = "aajfkdfvf_valid_name0"
b = "gdhdhsdsdeeeeex_valid_name1"


def clean_string(s: str) -> str:
    return s.split('_', 1)[1]


print(clean_string(a))  # valid_name0
print(clean_string(b))  # valid_name1
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're sure that just a '_' is your need, a string split will help:

```
fixed_a = '_'.join(a.split('_')[1:])
```

The worst case is that this pattern is not the only one you're looking at. Then, check this:

You need to know exactly what your 'valid_name' looks like, you could make a REGEX to achieve your need.
Check for standards, patterns and all those.
I'm pretty sure if is there a pattern, a Regex can handle.
I recommend [this site](https://regexr.com/) to do so.